# Binding to Collapse event in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Assuming that I have a Bootstrap Collapse:

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which element should I bind with for the following **JavaScript**:

```js
$("WhichSelectorGoesHere").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {})
```

Is it possible to bind all panels by class?

Unfortunately there is no `#myCollapsible` in the example in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

When the documentation lists the [**available events**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage), it's just a promise that it will always raise each particular event at a particular time.

*For example*, **`hidden.bs.collapse`** will be raised whenever:

> a collapsed element has been hidden from the user.

---

Whether or not anybody's listening to that event hasn't yet come into play.

To leverage this, or any other, event, we can use jQuery's [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach listeners on particular html elements to see if they raise particular events.

Where we add the listener depends on where the event is going to be raised and when we want to capture it.

### Simple Example:

Let's say you have the basic **HTML** structure for an Accordion control:

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1"><!--...--></div>
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2"><!--...--></div>
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel3"><!--...--></div>
</div>
```

In this case, each `panel` class is going to raise this event. So if want to capture it there, we just use the jQuery class selector to attach listeners to all the `.panel` objects like so:

```js
$('.panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    alert('Event fired on #' + e.currentTarget.id);
})
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DSGxz/)

---

### But Wait There's More...

In *HTML*, events will bubble from the [innermost element to the outermost element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) if unhandled.  So events raised for each individual `.panel`, can also be handled by the entire `.panel-group` *(or even the `body` element as they'll eventually work their way up there)*.

In the bootstrap examples page, they are using the id selector for the entire `panel-group`, which happens to be `#myCollapsible`, but in our case is `#accordion`.  If we want to handle the event there, we can simply change the jQuery selector as follows:

```js
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    alert('Event fired on #' + e.currentTarget.id);
})
```

Comment: one thing i want to mention is when use child collapsed elements, the alert fires 2 times.Once for the child with it's own id, and once for the parent with its id.This results in bad control.For example when open parent and child,then close parent.open parent again, child stays open.This is (personal) unwanted behavior.

Comment: To stop bubbling up you can use: `$('.panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Event fired on #' + e.currentTarget.id);
})`

Comment: Works that way on Bootstrap 2.3 too.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry for answering such an old question but I truly hope my input helps someone else.

I found this question because I needed to know how to get the `id` of the `.panel` that was subject to the event that was firing.

@KyleMit was very close to the answer I needed but not quite.

This:

```
$('.panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    alert('Event fired on #' + e.currentTarget.id);
})
```

does not fire the `alert`

This:

```
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    alert('Event fired on #' + e.currentTarget.id);
})
```

fires the alert with `is` `#accordion` which we do not need to get because we already know it to bind the `#accordion` to in the first place.

So to get the `id` of the `.panel` element that is being hidden you would use `e.target.id` instead of `e.currentTarget.id`. Like this:

```
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    alert('Event fired on #' + e.target.id);
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: What David Baucum said. Thank you and bookoo.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap's collapse class exposes a few events for hooking into collapse functionality:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-events