# Bootstrap handle collapse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used a template boostrap from themeforest, and they're really awesome but the problem is bootstrap is quite difficult to use.

In the left menu, it's divided into some collapsble `ul` and many `li`. Please, help me to catch "event" when the group ul is collapsed or expanded.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="margin-top:-15px;" >
    <li class="parent active">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <span>Tiêu chí tìm kiếm</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Chọn ngày theo dõi từ" id="datepickerFrom">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                    </span>
                </div><!-- input-group -->              
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Chọn ngày theo dõi đến" id="datepickerTo">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                     </span>
                </div><!-- input-group -->              
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this example, "Tiêu chí tìm kiếm" is what I want to handle when user click into this row to collapse its children li.

Comment: hi, please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936572/binding-to-collapse-event-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) answer

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are they using? If it's version 3, there's some documentation on the events in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage. For v 2.3.2, look at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to simply use the accordion for bootstrap.

On google you'll get [this](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php).

It is easy to understand and implement the same.