# browser scrollbar recenters centered accordion content in bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, resize, scrollbar, center

I have a question using the accordion feature of bootstrap 3.0.
The simple idea is to have 3 centered collapsable items on the page.

As soon as I expand an item which contains a lot of content (more than the browser can display in its length), the browser scrollbar appears and the whole content resizes and recenters itself a little. Its a small detail but its very annoying.

Please have a look at the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DSGxz/475/

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.container {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  padding-left: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard
          dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
          sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
          enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin
          coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
          nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel3">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch..
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;    
            background:lightgray;width:100%;'>
  About this SO Question: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/q/19936572/1366033'>Bootstrap3 Bind Collapse</a>
  <br/>Find documentation: <a href='http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage'>Bootstrap Collapse Usage</a>
  <br/>Fork This Skeleton Here <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>Bootrsap 3.0 Skeleton</a>
  <br/>
  <div>
```

Is there a way to avoid that little jump?